# Pop up menu script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a simple pop up menu where every time you click on the button, it will show 3 items, then it would close when you click outside of it.

```js
  let menu = document.getElementById("book-menu");

  const toggleMenu = () => menu.classList.toggle("show");

  window.onclick = (event) => {
    if (!event.target.matches('.homepage-button')) {
        if(menu.classList.contains('show')){
            menu.classList.remove('show')
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#book-menu {
    border: solid 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 20%;
    z-index: 1000;
    min-width: 10rem;
    padding: .5rem 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .book-item {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  .book-item:hover {
    background-color: red;
  }

  .show {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleMenu()" id="book-btn" class="homepage-button"> BOOK</button>

<div>
      <ul id="book-menu">
        <li class="book-item">Mitte</li>
        <li class="book-item">Kreuzberg</li>
        <li class="book-item">Zoo</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

It seems there is something wrong with the JavaScript part, because I cannot add the "show" class to the div regardless of what I do, what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Minor note, you are adding the show class to the <ul>, not the <div> as your last note might suggest. If you open the dev tools, you will see the class is being added/removed. It's just the priority of styles that isn't allowing the `display:block` to prevail.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `!important` in css to have more priority than previous class property.

```
.show {
   display: block !important;
 }
```

**Below is the final code:**

```js
  let menu = document.getElementById("book-menu");

  const toggleMenu = () => menu.classList.toggle("show");

  window.onclick = (event) => {
    if (!event.target.matches('.homepage-button')) {
        if(menu.classList.contains('show')){
            menu.classList.remove('show')
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#book-menu {
    border: solid 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 20%;
    z-index: 1000;
    min-width: 10rem;
    padding: .5rem 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .book-item {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  .book-item:hover {
    background-color: red;
  }

  .show {
    display: block !important;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleMenu()" id="book-btn" class="homepage-button"> BOOK</button>

<div>
      <ul id="book-menu">
        <li class="book-item">Mitte</li>
        <li class="book-item">Kreuzberg</li>
        <li class="book-item">Zoom</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply register the "click" event to Document Object and delegate what would happen if the user clicked a specific element and then close the menu should the user click anything that wasn't specified. See [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) for more details.

In the **Example A**, I have changed the ids into classes for the sake of simplicity and added a function that handles clicks on any `".book-item"`s for demonstration purposes.

In **Example B** I used an alternative HTML element [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog).

### Example A

```js
// Register Document Object to the "click" event.
document.onclick = event => {
  // Reference <ul>
  const menu = document.querySelector(".book-menu");
  /**
   * event.target is the element that the user has directly
   * clicked.
   * .classList is a DOMTokenList of classes assigned to it.
   */
  const clicked = event.target.classList;

  /**
   * If the user clicked an element that has ".book-btn"
   * add/remove ".active" from ".book-menu"
   *
   * Otherwise if the user clicked an element that has
   * ".book-menu" do nothing and end the function.
   *
   * Otherwise if the user clicked an element that has
   * ".book-item" call function openBook(book) 
   * event.target = book
   *
   * Otherwise if it's anything else, 
   * remove ".active" from ".book-menu"
   */
  if (clicked.contains("book-btn")) {
    menu.classList.toggle("active");
  } else if (clicked.contains("book-menu")) {
    return;
  } else if (clicked.contains("book-item")) {
    openBook(event.target);
  } else {
    menu.classList.remove("active");
  }
}

// For demo purposes
function openBook(book) {
  console.log(`${book.textContent} is opened.`);
}
```

```css
.book-menu {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 10rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.book-item {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.book-item:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="book-btn">BOOK</button>

<ul class="book-menu">
  <li class="book-item">Mitte</li>
  <li class="book-item">Kreuzberg</li>
  <li class="book-item">Zoo</li>
</ul>
```

### Example B

```js
window.onclick = toggle;

function toggle(event) {
  const dialogs = [...document.querySelectorAll("dialog")];
  const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll(".btn")];
  const clicked = event.target;

  if (clicked.matches(".btn")) {
    let index = buttons.indexOf(clicked);
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        dialogs[0].toggleAttribute("open");
        break;
      case 1:
        dialogs[1].showModal();
        break;
      case 2:
        dialogs[1].close();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  } else if (!event.target.closest("dialog")) {
    dialogs[0].close();
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">DIALOG</button>

<dialog>
  <header>
    <h2>Dialog</h2>
    <p>Background is clickable</p>
  </header>
  <menu>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">I</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">II</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">III</a></li>
  </menu>
</dialog>

<button class="btn">MODAL</button>

<dialog>
  <header>
    <button class="btn">X</button>
    <h2>Modal</h2>
    <p>Modal background is not clickable</p>
  </header>
  <menu>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">I</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">II</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">III</a></li>
  </menu>
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but the css `class` based declaration for `.show` has a lower precedence than the `id` based `#book-menu` declaration.

If you change your show class selector to:

```
#book-menu.show{...}
```

This will work (as will any other option where your updated CSS takes precedence over the element's default styling)

```js
let menu = document.getElementById("book-menu");

  const toggleMenu = () => menu.classList.toggle("show");

  window.onclick = (event) => {
    if (!event.target.matches('.homepage-button')) {
        if(menu.classList.contains('show')){
            menu.classList.remove('show')
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#book-menu {
    border: solid 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 20%;
    z-index: 1000;
    min-width: 10rem;
    padding: .5rem 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .book-item {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  .book-item:hover {
    background-color: red;
  }

  #book-menu.show {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleMenu()" id="book-btn" class="homepage-button"> BOOK</button>

<div>
      <ul id="book-menu">
        <li class="book-item">Mitte</li>
        <li class="book-item">Kreuzberg</li>
        <li class="book-item">Zoo</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have tried that but it still doesn't work...somehow

Comment: hmm, seems to work for me: https://codepen.io/scunliffe/pen/OJdEpOp?editors=1111

Comment: okay let me see what is the difference here

Comment: Somehow there are absolutely no difference between your code and the one I am running on my computer, but mine is still not working...

Comment: Are your CSS rules defined in the same order? and/or in the same file? that makes a difference to the priority too.